# Unexpected behaviour of Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm evaluating an expression and to me the result should be `True` but Mathematica is giving me a different result.

```
AllPositive = (A > 0 && B > 0 && X > 0 && P > 0 && L > 0);

NewCondition = ((B*P*L - X) > 0);
Simplify[(B*P*L - X) > 0, AllPositive && NewCondition]

NewCondition = ((B*P*L - X) > B);
Simplify[(B*P*L - X) > 0, AllPositive && NewCondition]

NewCondition = ((B*P - X) > B);
Simplify[(B*P - X) > 0, AllPositive && NewCondition]

NewCondition = (A*(B*P - X) > B);
Simplify[(B*P - X) > 0, AllPositive && NewCondition]

NewCondition = (A*(B*P*L - X) > B);
Simplify[(B*P*L - X) > 0, AllPositive && NewCondition]
```

Results:

```
True

True

True

True

B L P > X
```

Shouldn't the last `Simplify` also return `True`?

Comment: Even `NewCondition = (B*P*L - X > B/A);
Simplify[{B/A > 0, (B*P*L - X) > 0}, AllPositive && NewCondition]` does not work as expected, yielding `{True, B L P > X}`